# No argument given for formal parameter

Tags: c#, class, console

I'm getting the error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'value' of 'CsvLines.CsvLines(string, string, string, string, string)'

The below is where I add the values to my class.

```
List<CsvLines> valuesList = new List<CsvLines>();

            Console.WriteLine("Currently filtering " + fileName);

            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                // Change the logic here depending on what we want from the file. Depending on the list it might be better to filter by things we want.
                if (line.Contains("|")) //Add variable here to search for in the files
                {
                    string[] csvFields = line.Split('|');
                    CsvLines lines = new CsvLines
                    {
                        Value = csvFields[0],
                        Name = csvFields[1],
                        Spanish = csvFields[2],
                        French = csvFields[3],
                        Russian = csvFields[4]
                    };

                    valuesList.Add(new CsvLines(lines.Value, lines.Name, lines.Spanish, lines.French, lines.Russian));
                }

                fileRowCount++;
            }
```

Below is my actual class:

```
namespace LogHarvester
{
    public class CsvLines
    {
    public string Value { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Spanish { set; get; }
    public string French { set; get; }
    public string Russian { set; get; }

    public CsvLines(string value, string name, string spanish, string french, string russian)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.Name = name;
        this.Spanish = spanish;
        this.French = french;
        this.Russian = russian;
    }

  }
}
```

I'd give you more information but I've done some searching and I honestly don't know, many searches returned that I may need a base constructor, but I'm unsure how that will solve the problem.

I intend to parse each line and then insert it into an array, before assigning the array positions to the values, and from there I then add them to a list of said Class "CsvLines". Any help would be much appreciated, if you need any more information I'll try my best to give it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this declaration:

```
CsvLines lines = new CsvLines
{
    Value = csvFields[0],
    Name = csvFields[1],
    Spanish = csvFields[2],
    French = csvFields[3],
    Russian = csvFields[4]
};
```

This way you are essentially calling the constructor with no arguments (e.g. `new CsvLines()`), that does not exists. You should define a default constructor in your class.

Alternatively, there is no need to create two new `CsvLines` objects (or define a default constructor), just:

```
valuesList.Add(new CsvLines(csvFields[0], csvFields[1], csvFields[2], csvFields[3], csvFields[4]));
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful, I didn't realise you would need an empty constructor if you were going to initialise them in run-time instead. Thanks for clearing that up.